Why do I get bad or no results with the youtube api to search for playlists but good results manually searching? Can I fix this?
I use the youtube API to search for albums with Excel and today it started giving me either really bad results or none at all. For example I tried having Excel search Blue Cult - Mirrors and get 4 results with them all being nothing like the search term
Part of the bogus search results
I used this to search
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Blue%20%20Cult%20-%20Mirrors&type=playlist&key=REDACTED&order=relevance&maxResults=10
But if I manually search the term going on to google's website, I get proper results
Results when searching YouTube manually
This used to work fine until I tried to go through the searches that failed to return good results today so I'm not sure if something happened or if I need to change something. Any idea on what I can do?

Is there any VBA you meant to share with us?  If not, it's not really clear exactly what's going on here.

Does https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/Webscrap_any_website/commit/72ad565c6694008ae783f0e3ab32ca2d9c288124#diff-4c2a5e01291764de0dde7839957b5d05e02b1adc which web-scrapes YouTube UI search results solve your issue?
